# How do I stream a file and keep the encoding as ansi (windows-1252) in Node.js

Tags: node.js, character-encoding

I use Formidable to upload a file to my Node-js webserver (local installation for testing). The file is in ansi (iso-8859-1) before I upload it, and it still is when it has been uploaded, I've checked the file using Notepad++.

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

            csv
            .fromPath(files.upfile.path, {headers: true})
            .on("record", function(data){
                console.log(data.adresse);
            })
            .on("end", function(){
                console.log("done");
            });

            res.end(console.log("form done"));

        });
```

As soon as I use a stream or a plugin(fast-csv in this case) that uses a node fs to stream the content, the encoding is botched. See the data below, the ? should be the danish character ø.

```
{adresse: 'Niver?d By, Karlebo'}
```

Can anyone tell me why?

**Update:**

It worked by streaming the uploaded file and using Iconv to convert it.

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();


        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

            console.log(files.upfile.path);

            var stream = fs.createReadStream(files.upfile.path);

            var csvStream = csv({headers : true})
             .on("record", function(data){
                 var db = req.db;

                // Set our collection
                var collection = db.get('bbrcollection');

                // Submit to the DB
                collection.insert(data, function (err, doc) {

                //console.log(data);

                    if (err) {
                        // If it failed, return error
                        console.log("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
                    }
                });
             })
             .on("end", function(){
                 console.log("done");
             });

            stream
                .pipe(new Iconv('WINDOWS-1252', 'UTF-8'))
                .pipe(csvStream);

        });


  res.render('upload', { title: 'upload file'});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the encoding to utf8 to use the contents in javascript. Both [iconv](https://www.npmjs.org/package/iconv) and [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.org/package/iconv-lite) should be able to do that for you.

Comment: When should I do this? while streaming? while saving the file with Formidable or even before?

Comment: Both modules support streaming, so you could stream a copy of the file to one of these modules and parse it, while keeping the original on disk via Formidable (if you need to keep a copy on disk that is). Or do it after the files are all saved to disk (like you are doing now).