# Getting replacement character (65533) when reading in file using Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, character-encoding

In my Meteor app, I have a method that reads in a .csv file and inserts it into a collection. This file is in Spanish, and so includes characters like ó (`&oacute;`). Within the method, I am running `console.log(row[3][9] + ' is ' + row[3].charCodeAt(9));` which works fine unless it is a special character, in which case I always get `"? is 65533"` in the console. I'm not very familiar with character encoding methods, but am confused as to why this would be encoded at all since it is coming from a .csv file.

A sample of the file:

> 1,1,1,"Apreciación de directivos, profesores, estudiantes y personal administrativo sobre la claridad en los objetivos del programa",Encuesta Realizada,,,,,,,4.30,b
>   1,1,2,"Apreciación de directivos, profesores, estudiantes, visitantes y personal administrativo de la capacidad que ha demostrado el programa a lo largo de su trayectoria para lograr dichos objetivos ",Encuesta Realizada,,,,,,,3.97,v
>   2,2,3,Existencia de evidencia de los proceso de selección de estudiantes con criterios bien definidos en los últimos 5 años. ,Actas de admisión Reglamento general reglamento estudiantil Documento Maestro ,,,,,,,4.54,b
>   2,2,4,Existencia de evidencia de estrategias implementadas en los últimos 5 años para asegurar un número de estudiantes adecuado que le den sostenibilidad al programa.,Página web folletos Resoluciones de las universidades de apoyos a estudiantes Solicitudes al consejo de Rectores ,,,,,,,4.00,b

the JavaScript method being used to upload and read-in the file:

```js
Meteor.methods({
 'uploadFile':function(fileid,filename){
  var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
  var file = Uploads.find({_id:fileid});
  var listNewAll = [];
  Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
   var filepath = '/imports/uploads' + '-' + fileid + '-' + filename;
   CSV().from.stream(
   fs.createReadStream(filepath),
   {'escape':'\\'})
   .on('record', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(row,index){
    fullList.insert({
     'Factor':row[0],
     'Caracteristica':row[1],
     'Number':row[2],
     'Indicador':row[3],
     'Razon':row[4],
     'UA':row[5],
     'UC':row[6],
     'UM':row[7],
     'UCe':row[8],
     'UCo':row[9],
     'US':row[10],
     'Tot':row[11],
     'Color':row[12],
    })
    console.log(row[3][9] + ' is ' + row[3].charCodeAt(9));
    console.log(row[3].charCodeAt(9) == 243);
   }, function(error){
    console.log(error);
   }))
   .on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
   })
   .on('end', function(count){
    
   })
  },100);
  
 }
})
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using fast-csv. Could be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664074/how-do-i-stream-a-file-and-keep-the-encoding-as-ansi-windows-1252-in-node-js

Comment: as far as I'm aware I am not using fast-csv. I'm using FS.collection to upload the file

Comment: Where is the `CSV` object defined? Is that something you created or did it come from a package? If it came from a package, which one?

Comment: it's just a file on my computer that I upload to the website. At this point I've created a new, better way to access it per https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-working-with-csv-file-import-with-fields-mapping/649/3 (the second method), but it still doesn't deploy. Using the new method, it takes a csv file from the private directory of the project.